# middle line with symbol in circle in css3

Tags: html, css

I want to show 3 circles horizontally and between it should be with dotted line and grater than symbol in between all circles.
when use of media queries for certain limit its show be vertically both circle and that middle line.

```
 <div class="cir_content">
    <div class="shape_circle">Track 
    </div>
 </div>
 .shape_circle{
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    border-radius:250px;
        background:#e3d356;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
.cir_container{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 2% 0px;
  }
 .cir_content{
    display:inline-block;
    width:32%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
 }
 .cir_cont{
        display:block;
        width:1200px;
 }
```

How to do that?

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/3WBCJ/)

Comment: Could you please explain the issue clearly , what aren't you managing? Also, you talk about media queries but there aren't any in your code.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you trying to vertically center the text in the circles? if so just set `line-height: 160px;` on `.shape_circle` I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WBCJ/4/)